# How to fix issue where python won't call a function from within a loop

Tags: python-3.x

At the yes/no loop, the program won't call the function to re-perform a calculation. Instead, it asks to compute another gcd repeatedly instead of calling the specified function.

I've tried re-inputting the whole function into the question loop if the user inputs yes, but that did not work either.

```
def gcd(n,m):
    if(m==0):
        return n
    else:
        return gcd(m,n%m)

n = int(input("Enter a positive whole number:"))
while True:
    if n <= 0:
        print ("The number entered is not a positive number!, please try again")
        n = int(input("Enter a positive whole number : "))
    if n > 0: break

m = int(input("Enter a second positive whole number:"))
while True:
    if m <= 0:
        print ("The number entered is not a positive number!, please try again")
        m = int(input("Enter a positive whole number : "))
    if m > 0: break

GCD = gcd(n,m)

print("The GCD of the two numbers you entered is:" ,GCD)



while True:
    a = input("Compute another GCD? Enter y/n:").lower()
    if a=="y":
        gcd(n,m)
    elif a=="n":
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid entry. Please enter either y/n:")

print("Goodbye!")
```

Expected results is that it calls the function gcd(n,m) and re-performs a calculation. Actual results is that it asks to perform another calculation without having actually completed a second calculation.

Comment: Looks like you can either wrap the function call with a `print()` statement OR you can change the `return`'s to `print`'s inside your `gcd()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called. The problem is that you don't do anything with its return value.

You will also need to ask the user for new input. In order to not repeat the same code again you can have a function that does that.

Then the whole code becomes:

```
def get_2_numbers():
    n = int(input("Enter a positive whole number:"))
    while True:
        if n <= 0:
            print ("The number entered is not a positive number!, please try again")
            n = int(input("Enter a positive whole number : "))
        if n > 0: break

    m = int(input("Enter a second positive whole number:"))
    while True:
        if m <= 0:
            print ("The number entered is not a positive number!, please try again")
            m = int(input("Enter a positive whole number : "))
        if m > 0: break

    return n, m

def gcd(n,m):
    if(m==0):
        return n
    else:
        return gcd(m,n%m)

a, b = get_2_numbers()

while True:
    answer = input("Compute another GCD? Enter y/n:").lower()
    if answer == "y":
        print(gcd(a, b))
        a, b = get_2_numbers()
    elif answer == "n":
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid entry. Please enter either y/n:")

print("Goodbye!")
```

A small downside is that the user will have to answer `y` even before the first calculation, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: But I am not looking to print the output of the previous calculation. I am actually trying to get it to "goto"/go back the to the gcd(n,m) calculation, and allow the user to do another, or as many calculations as they would like.

Comment: That code doesn't return the result of the first calculation. And if you click yes for a second calculation, you get a traceback error, I've played with a bit to see if I could get it to work, using the concepts you explained but no luck just yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help in any event. I am very new to python (just a few weeks) and the last programming I did before that was qbasic.